# Simple Hello World Grails Form Submission

Tags: grails, web

I am new to Grails and I am trying to get a very simple example to work. I should just submit a form and display "Hello World" on the screen. It consists of the following controller:

```
package surface

class SearchController {

 def index() {
    render(view: "search")
 }

 def result() {
    render "Hello World"
 }
}
```

and a view, with the form:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<g:form name="searchform" url="result">
<g:textArea cols="80" rows="30" name="searchfield"/>
<g:actionSubmit value="Ask"/>
</g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on "Ask" I get a 404 error but the browser correctly accesses "/surface/search/result". When I enter that address directly without using the form the "Hello World" appears correctly. This is probably a no-brainer but I seem to be unable to find out why this does not work from the documentation.

Comment: You should use "action" instead of "url", so: `<g:form name="searchform" action="result">`

Comment: Well in that case the Grails documentation has an error.

Comment: It has not, "action" is the first parameter in the documentation ;-) I haven't used the "url" yet, but there are cases, when it is useful. For you, it is not necessary to point to the URL of the action, rather use the action name, which is mapped to the URL via UrlMappings.groovy. So, when you change the mapping, you don't need to change the form "url" in your views.

Comment: The first example in the Grails documentation tells me to do it the following way: <g:form name="myForm" url="[controller:'book',action:'list']">...</g:form>. This clearly has the url parameter but does not work as expected (by me). Nevertheless, it works now if I put the action attribute directly into the submit button. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Complementing the @Tom Metz answer, what you need to keep in mind in the Grails controller structure is that every public method is considered an [action](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#understandingControllersAndActions). This action is mapped to a url. In your example will exists `/search/index` and `/search/result` (controller + action).

The documentation of the `g.form` is corret, since this says that;

> url (optional) - A map containing the action,controller,id etc.

So to correct your view you can set the action as commented or you can adjust the way you use url:

```
<g:form name="myForm" url="[action:'result',controller:'search']">
```

Comment: Well, this was how I did have it in the first place. It does not work that way. But It works now if I put the action directly into the submit button. Thanks for the help anyways.